# Function for scanning string - what's the problem?

Tags: c, string, pointers, char, realloc

```
char* scanString()
{
    char* str = NULL;
    char* temp = NULL;
    int  numOfChars = 0;
    char c = '0';
    while (c != '\n')
    {
        scanf(" %c", &c);
        if (c != '\n')
        {
            if (numOfChars == 0)
            {
                char* str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
                char* temp = str;
                if (str == NULL)
                    return str;
                str[0] = c;
                numOfChars++;
            }
            else
            {
                str = (char*)realloc(str, sizeof(char) * (numOfChars + 1));
                str[numOfChars] = c;
                if (str == NULL)
                    return temp;
                else
                {
                    temp = str;
                    numOfChars++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    str = (char*)realloc(str, sizeof(char) * (numOfChars+1));
    if (str == NULL)
    {
        str = temp;
        return str;
    }
    str[numOfChars] = '\0';
    return str;
}
int main()
{
    char* m;
    printf("write:\n");
    m = scanString();
    printf("%s\n", m);
}
```

I tried to create a function for scanning a string of unknown size char by char and i don't know what'ss the problem here. Btw please don't approach me to any other code or try to use different libraries.

Comment: Because of the leading space in the `scanf` format string `" %c"`, the `scanf` function will skip all white-space, which includes newline. So `c` will *never* be a newline `'\n'`.

Comment: You didn't actually say what the 'problem' is.

Answer (score 3):

There is one big error and some inconsistencies.

The big error is here:

```
        if (numOfChars == 0)
        {
            char* str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)); // Oops a new var!
            char* temp = str;                        // and another one!
            if (str == NULL)
                return str;
            str[0] = c;
            numOfChars++;
        }
```

You declare 2 new variables in that bloc that will hide the variables of outer scope. As a result, the first character will be lost and you will get a random value.

The inconsistencies:

- `temp` is useless and should be removed
- you read with a format `" %c"`. The format will skip any blank character **including `\n`**. It should be `"%c"`
- you fail to test the return value of `scanf`. On end of file (of any other read error) you will enter an endless loop. It should be:

  ```
        if (1 != scanf("%c", &c)) break;
  ```

Once this is fixed, you should get the expected output, but other improvements are still possible:

- the idiomatic way to read one character is `getc` or `getchar`
- allocating one character at a time is an anti-pattern because (re-)allocation is a rather expensive operation. For a real world program, you should always allocate a bunch or memory and keep track of the available part
- `sizeof(char)` **is** 1 per standard
- the distinction for `numOfChars == 0` is useless. `realloc` on a NULL pointer is the same of `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is overly complicated and wrong **and** as stated in a comment you need to replace the format string `" %c"` with `"%c"`.

The main problem is here:

```
if (numOfChars == 0)
{
  char* str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

You declare a new `str` variable which shadows the `str` variable you've declared at the beginning of the function.

Just replace `char* str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char))` with `str = malloc(sizeof(char));`. BTW the cast is not necessary.

You have the same problem with `temp`.

The code below is entirely based on your code, but it is simpler and correct. Basically the case where `numOfChars` is 0 should not be treated specially. You can just use `realloc`, because `realloc(NULL, foo)` is equivalent to `malloc(foo)` .

```
char* scanString()
{
  char* str = NULL;
  char* temp = NULL;
  int  numOfChars = 0;
  char c = '0';
  while (c != '\n')
  {
    scanf("%c", &c);
    if (c != '\n')
    {
      str = realloc(str, sizeof(char) * (numOfChars + 1));
      if (str == NULL)
        return temp;
      
      str[numOfChars] = c;
      temp = str;
      numOfChars++;
    }
  }
   
  str = realloc(str, sizeof(char) * (numOfChars + 1));
  if (str == NULL)
  {
    str = temp;
    return str;
  }
  str[numOfChars] = '\0';
  return str;
}
```

Or even simpler:

```
char* scanString()
{
  char* str = NULL;
  char* temp = NULL;
  int  numOfChars = 0;
  char c = '0';
  while (c != '\n')
  {
    scanf("%c", &c);

    str = realloc(str, sizeof(char) * (numOfChars + 1));
    if (str == NULL)
      return temp;

    str[numOfChars] = c;
    temp = str;

    if (c == '\n')
    {
      str[numOfChars] = '\0';
    }

    numOfChars++;
  }

  return str;
}
```